# Remove same values From array containing multiple value

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate an array and keep only one value if there are more found with the same value.

Example:

`const arrayElement = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'blue'];`

To

`const arrayElement = ['red', 'white', 'blue'];`

How can I do that with vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicate from your array via multiple ways

Using `Set`

Simple and easy way use `new Set` to remove duplicates from your `arrays`

Run snippet below.

```js
const arrayElement = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'blue']; 

const unique = [...new Set(arrayElement)];

console.log(unique)
```

Using `.filter`

```js
const arrayElement = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'blue']; 

const removeDup = arrayElement.filter(function(i, x) {
    return arrayElement.indexOf(i) == x;
})

console.log(removeDup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates from your existing array and keeping only one,

```js
const arrayElement = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'blue'];
console.log([...new Set(arrayElement)]);
```